# GitHub error - Key is invalid. You must supply a key in OpenSSH public key format

Tags: git

EDIT: solved I was opening id_ed25519 not id_ed25519.pub.

When I try to paste my SSH key into GitHub > Settings > SSH and GPG keys > New SSH key, I get the error:

Key is invalid. You must supply a key in OpenSSH public key format

I created the SSH key and added it to the SSH agent successfully as per these instructions: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent.

I found the file and copied the key to my clipboard using these instructions: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

But the text field "Key" in https://github.com/settings/ssh/new says:

"Begins with 'ssh-rsa'..." and then gives a whole other variety of ways the key can start.

But mine starts:

-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAA

Can anyone help me please? I followed the instructions to the letter. Do I need to add something like 'ssh-rsa' to my key for it to work?

Comment: You should copy your **public** key into GitHub, not your private key.

Comment: Thanks I was opening id_ed25519 not id_ed25519.pub.

Answer (score 12):

When you create ssh keys you get 2 key's.

One is the public key with "*.pub" and one private key.

You can read both keys if you open the files.

The private key begins with something like:
**----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----**

The public key starts with the Digital Signature Algorithm
it is a one row string

You have to copy the "*.pub" to the git server or on other servers if you work with ssh.

Never give away your private key and use always a password with your keys if someone copy or steal the private key.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same issue!

At the end of the day, I was trying to paste the wrong key; make sure you open the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file, not only `~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34032342)

Answer (score 4):

Also a common mistake is that people dont copy the full key because they open it with `nano` and some times it looks somethig like this which is not the complete key

[image: termial ss]

You can try using `vim id_rsa.pub` to visualize the complete key

Answer (score 0):

**The error is usually one of the following:**

- Copy from `id_rsa`, `id_rsa.pub` in some scenarios, open it directly and it will be misformatted
- Make sure you are pasting the **public key** `id_rsa.pub` or the **private key** `id_rsa`; and that you are copying all of the text
- in the top right corner of your GitHub account, or `Setting` in the `Blog` repository.
- Paste the wrong page, `Secrets` or `Deploy keys`; the former is common for deploying Hexo Blog, the latter is common for push

**Solutions:**

```bash
clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub      # Copy directly to clipboard
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub         # Copy after exporting to the terminal
Open with notepad, notepad++  # and copy and paste
```

Comment: Thank you, the solution with copying after exporting to the terminal solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial I was following told me to generate a **DSA** key when it should have been telling me to generate a **RSA** key! Guess the tutorial was a little dated maybe. The rest of it seemed to work okay. Hope that helps someone. Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy Public key not private. To do this open /.ssh/YourKeyFile.**pub**

in terminal, you can do this by code below:

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/YourKeyFile.pub
```

Comment: for Ubuntu user [here](https://gist.github.com/diegopacheco/75de31680b3eaeb8824e994b81889f82)